# Ищу компонент TTBXImageList для Delphi

Tags: delphi, поиск-библиотек, vcl, компоненты

Пытаюсь реанимировать старый проект на Delphi, который требует класс TTBXImageList. Обнаружил [TBX](https://github.com/plashenkov/TBX) (надстройка к Toolbar2000), но там этого нет.
При этом в интернете указанный компонент некогда обсуждали.
Помогите, пожалуйста, его обнаружить.

Answer (score 2):

Есть [TBX](https://bitbucket.org/sas_team/sas.requires/src/default/tbx/) и [Toolbar2000](https://bitbucket.org/sas_team/sas.requires/src/default/tb2k/). До сих пор используем эти компоненты, особых багов не замечено.

Собираются в Delphi 2007 - Delphi 10.3, вносились незначительные изменения для добавления совместимости - можете посмотреть по истории коммитов, какие именно.

Искомый класс TTBXImageList находится в юните [TBXGraphics.pas](https://bitbucket.org/sas_team/sas.requires/src/465c8a84c01b4de7049867503c46a18da4088d19/tbx/TBXGraphics.pas#lines-199).

Comment: Благодарю, но пакеты под D7 там отсутствуют...

Comment: @zed offtopic: SASPlanet ожил?

Comment: @The_Immortal Так сделайте. По-моему, эти же сорцы мы и под D7 использовали, но со временем что-то могло и поломаться.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Он вроде и не умирал, просто замедлился. Присылайте пулл-реквесты, если что :)

Comment: @zed да сделал, один фиг ошибки сыпятся... Замучился уже :( https://www.sql.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotomsg&tid=265579&msg=21775017

Answer (score 1):

Если честно, глючноватый был компонент. Помню, что в нём что-то исправляли всем миром, поскольку автор перестал над ним работать. Хотя на тот момент его возможности были интересны. Он не входит в Toolbar2000, а был в пакете  [TBX v.2.2 Alpha](https://torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=1266), а, вот, который, в свою очередь, уже требует Toolbar2000.

Comment: А приведенный мною TBX - это уже какая-то кастомная доработка того TBX получается откуда этот ImageList почему-то выпилили?

Comment: @The_Immortal вполне возможно, поскольку автор (один из них) - Alex Denisov. Была ветка на одном из форумов, где правили компонент из TBX 2.2, но вот как-то не получается найти эту ссылку. Возможно, все правки сейчас уже в git'е

Comment: @ Viktor Tomilov жаль, однако, что при попытке скомпилить оттуда tbx_d7.dpk нарываешься на кучу ошибок, начиная с _DrawTextW

Comment: @The_Immortal D7 у нас, увы, уже нет. Ту ветку, как ни искал, не нашёл, только огрызки: https://www.sql.ru/forum/265579-1/toolbar-2000-2-1-8-tbx-2-2-alpha-repacked